Quarkus Artemis Jms library does not deliver message to dead-letter-queue on ActiveMQ Artemis
I am currently implementing inside a Quarkus project a JMS consumer which listens to a anycast queue ("my.edu.queue") on ActiveMQ Artemis (version 2.32.0). What I want to test is how the message is delivered to dead-letter queue if let's say some business error happens. I simulated the business error for every fifth message (just throw exception).
From the looks at the code from ActiveMQ Artemis examples (dead-letter example) the code for  dead-letter seems straight forward. I have implemented the functionality in the same way as it is in the example (as I thought), except that I have done it with "quarkus-artemis-jms" library. The problem with the code or maybe my broker setup is that I do not get message inside dead letter queue when I do Session.rollback(). The code of my JmsMessageConsumer looks following if someone can from the first look guess what I am doing wrong. I have also set the max-delivery-attempts inside broker.xml to 0 for my queue (I have added link to my project where every file is in there).
@ApplicationScoped
public class JmsMessageConsumer {

   private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JmsMessageConsumer.class.getName());

   @Inject
   ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

   private JMSContext context;
   private Connection connection;
   private Session session;
   private MessageConsumer consumer;
   private MessageProducer dlqProducer;

   @ConfigProperty(name = "my.edu.queue.name", defaultValue = "my.edu.queue")
   String queueName;

   private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);


   void onStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) throws JMSException {
      connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
      session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);

      Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
      consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

      Queue dlq = session.createQueue(queueName + ".dlq");
      dlqProducer = session.createProducer(dlq);

      connection.start();

      receiveMessages();
   }

   void onStop(@Observes ShutdownEvent ev) throws JMSException {
      connection.close();
   }

   private void receiveMessages() {
      try {
         consumer.setMessageListener(message -> {
            try {
               processMessage(message.getBody(String.class));
               session.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               log.severe("Error processing message: %s".formatted(e.getMessage()));
               try {
                  // sendToDLQ(message);
                  session.rollback();
               } catch (JMSException ex) {
                  throw new RuntimeException(ex);
               }
            }
         });
      } catch (JMSException e) {
         log.severe("Error setting message listener: %s".formatted(e.getMessage()));
      }
   }

   private void processMessage(String text) {
      counter.incrementAndGet();
      if (counter.get() % 5 == 0) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Error in business logic");
      }
      log.info("Processed message: " + text);
   }

}


The whole project (which is really simple) with all the configuration files can be found here. My broker.xml can be found inside src/resources/broker_conf/broker.xml.

The messages are not sent to the dead letter address because max-delivery-attempts is 0. You must set max-delivery-attempts to a positive value to send the undelivered messages to the dead letter address, see QueueImpl.
To send the messages to the dead letter address after the first rollback set max-delivery-attempts to 1, i.e.
<address-setting match="#">
   <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
   <max-delivery-attempts>1</max-delivery-attempts>
... 



What a stupid error :/. Thanks for help . Now it works :).
